# Not able to access the provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I have a simple provider class:-

```
class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   int count;
   void updateCount() {
     count = count + 1;
     notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

I am attaching this provider to the following class:-

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => DataProvider(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: raisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Provider.of<DataProvider>(context).updateCount();
          }
           child: Text("Click!")
         ),
       ),
     ),
   }
```

and its Giving me the following error:-

```
 I/flutter (32011): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<DataProvider> above this MyWidget 
 Widget
 I/flutter (32011): To fix, please:
 I/flutter (32011):   * Ensure the Provider<DataProvider> is an ancestor to this MyWidget Widget
 I/flutter (32011):   * Provide types to Provider<DataProvider>
 I/flutter (32011):   * Provide types to Consumer<DataProvider>
 I/flutter (32011):   * Provide types to Provider.of<DataProvider>()
 I/flutter (32011):   * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
```

What could be the reason for this?

**Edit:-**
It's working fine when I access the provider from any child widget of the widget where I have defined. `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling `Provider.of<DataProvider>(context).updateCount()` using the wrong `context`. You are using the `context` provided by the `build` method, which is higher up the hierarchy than the Provider you are trying to access. You need to use a `context` that belongs to a descendant (lower down the hierarchy) of the Provider.

Wrap your `Scaffold` in a `Builder` widget, which exposes a new `context` at that level in the widget hierarchy, and use that context instead.

You could also use a `Consumer`, although it would not be optimal in your example because `Consumer` will rebuild every time `notifyListeners()` is called in the Provider, which would be redundant because your UI does not change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `raisedButton` in a `Consumer`.

> The Consumer widget has two main purposes:
>
> It allows obtaining a value from a provider when we don't have a
>   BuildContext that is a descendant of said provider, and therefore
>   cannot use Provider.of. This scenario typically happens when the
>   widget that creates the provider is also one of its consumers, like in
>   the following example:
>
> ```
> @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   return ChangeNotifierProvider(
>     create: (_) => Foo(),
>     child: Text(Provider.of<Foo>(context).value),
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> This example will throw a ProviderNotFoundException, because
>   Provider.of is called with a BuildContext that is an ancestor of the
>   provider.
>
> Instead, we can use the Consumer widget, that will call Provider.of
>   with its own BuildContext.
>
> Using Consumer, the previous example will become:
>
> ```
> @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   return ChangeNotifierProvider(
>     create: (_) => Foo(),
>     child: Consumer<Foo>(
>       builder: (_, foo, __) => Text(foo.value),
>     },
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> This won't throw a ProviderNotFoundException and will correctly build
>   the Text. It will also update the Text whenever the value foo changes.

See: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Having the Scaffold inside the Builder widget helped me to resolve the issue with Provider

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<StatusViewModel>(
      create: (context) => StatusViewModel(),
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context){
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("this is appbar"),    
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);}
```